# How to specify YAML metadata in Markdown for Pandoc Beamer slides?

Tags: yaml, pandoc, beamer

I am trying to use a YAML metadata block to specify some document properties in a Markdown document for Pandoc that I am going to convert to LaTeX Beamer. I read the description here: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block and attempted the following document:

```
---
title: Some title
---

# This is a test slideshow.

## This should turn into a slide...

...with some content.
```

I convert the file to PDF using `pandoc -t beamer file.md -V theme:SomeTheme -o file.pdf`. It seems to work correctly with the theme etc., except that the YAML block at the beginning of the document is converted into a table in the first slide containing a top and bottom rule and the text "title: Some title". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your metadata doesn't work as mine works fine.

**Try doing (with a space after the title)**:

```
---
title: Some title

---

# This is a test slideshow.

## This should turn into a slide...

...with some content.
```

**Or (with periods)**:

```
---
title: Some title

...

# This is a test slideshow.

## This should turn into a slide...

...with some content.
```

**Or (with quotes)**:

```
---
title: "Some title"

---

# This is a test slideshow.

## This should turn into a slide...

...with some content.
```

Do these all work?

Comment: Indeed, they all work. Strangely, my original example also works now. I was previously trying this with an earlier version of Pandoc (I do not remember which). It works now with version 1.12.2.1.