# Pandoc: Template with YAML metadata

Tags: arrays, templates, yaml, pandoc

I use pandoc for generate index.html with YAML metadata. I know iterate associative arrays from pandoc template:

**YAML**:

```
- Author: Mastropiero
- Author: Gunter Fraggen
```

**TEMPLATE**:

```
$for(author)$
  $author$
$endfor$
```

But... How to iterate lists **without key**?

**YAML**:

```
- Author:
  - [Value1, Value2]
  - [Value1B, Value2B]
```

**TEMPLATE**:

```
$for(author)$
  ... // how works?
$endfor$
```

Answer (score 19):

As your template shows, within a loop pandoc makes a local variable with the same name as the array ('author' in your case). So to iterate through the inner list, simply use the same 'for' mechanism on the inner variable.

Thus, you should use

**TEMPLATE**

```
$for(author)$
   $for(author)$
      $author$
   $endfor$
$endfor
```

You can also use $sep$ to specify a separator to use between the elements of the list.

Note that if the inner list has elements with different meanings (rather than just a list) then you should use a list of dictionaries.

**YAML**

```
Author:
  - {name: Iain Banks, book: The Algebraist}
  - {name: Isaac Asimov, book: Foundation}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
$for(author)$
    $author.name$ wrote $author.book$
$endfor$
```

Comment: Very helpful! Can you include an example of how to specify` $sep$`?

Comment: Just add `$sep$separator` inside the loop. `separator` could be `\\\` for example.