# pandoc template expands embedded e-mail multiple times

Tags: pandoc, beamer

I'm presently modifying the [default pandoc template for Beamer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.beamer) so that the  email address of the presentation's author can be added. However, when I try to add a *valid* e-mail address the `for` statement ends up by repetitively embedding the value even though there is only a single value.

Take for example:

```
---
email: 'toad@gmail.com'
---
```

With the following [templated variable](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#using-variables-in-templates):

```
$for(email)$ \href{mailto:$email$}{\nolinkurl{$email$}}$sep$ \and $endfor$
```

I end up receiving:

```
\href{mailto:\href{mailto:toad@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{toad@gmail.com}}}{\nolinkurl{\href{mailto:toad@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{toad@gmail.com}}}}
```

instead of the desired:

```
\href{mailto:toad@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{toad@gmail.com}}
```

If instead I set `email` to be a non-valid address, e.g.

```
---
email: 'toad'
---
```

I receive the value `toad` embedded. Only when I begin to add the `@` sign and an additional letter after does the repetitive embedding become present. I've searched through the docs to no avail as to what might be causing this behavior.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either with pandoc 17.1; it might have to do with where you set this in the template. Are you redefining `\titlepage`?

Answer (score 0):

When using `for`, the templating system expects an array. In YAML an array can be written e.g. like this:

```
---
email:
  - 'toad@gmail.com'
---
```

Edit: but that doesn't seem to be the issue, cannot reproduce with pandoc 1.18

Comment: I thought based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483499/pandoc-template-with-yaml-metadata that the key approach above would be okay.

Comment: indeed, see my edit... can you try in the newest pandoc version?